# C++ - base class variables are returned 0 when setting values via parameterzied constructor

Tags: c++

I have been trying to figure out the error past an hour, so asking .
Even though I have my parameterized constructor accepting default length,breadth  it shows them correctly in same class but returns both of them 0 in derived class ***box***  when I am trying to use it there.

```
#include<iostream>
class rectangle
{

    protected :
    //int length=12,breadth=13; // LINE A
    int length,breadth;         // LINE B

public: 


    rectangle(){}  // Empty default constructor
    rectangle (int len , int br)
    {
    length =len ,breadth =br;

    }

void area_rect()
    {
    std::cout << "\n Area is " << (length*breadth);
    std::cout << "\n Length,Breadth : " << length << "  "<<breadth<< "\n";
    }   

};

class box : public rectangle
{   
    int depth;
    public:
    box() {}   // Again empty constructor of derived class
    box(int d)
    {
    depth = d;
    }

    void area_box()
    {
    std::cout << "VOLUME IS : "<<(length*breadth*depth)<< "\n";
    }

};


int main()

{
rectangle r(10,20);
r.area_rect();
box b(30);
b.area_box();

return 0;
}
```

-- uncommenting line B, and Commenting A gives

```
 Area is 200
 Length,Breadth : 10  20
VOLUME IS : 0
```

-- uncommenting line A, and Commenting B gives

```
 Area is 200
 Length,Breadth : 10  20
VOLUME IS : 4680
```

Comment: You are not calling `rectangle`'s parametrized constructor from `box`.

Comment: This is not how to write constructors. Base classes and members should be initialized in the initializer list, after a colon, before the constructor body. This is completely missing from your code.

Comment: What are you asking though? What is your expectation when running this line: `b.area_box();`?

Comment: What did you expect `length` and 'breadth` to be set to when you execute `box b(30);`?

Answer (score 4):

You always should initialize simple member variables in the constructor:

```
   rectangle() : length(0), breadth(0) {};
```

otherwise they stay "uninitialized" which means they have a garbage value.

For object member variables (e.g. if you had `std::string color;` as another private member variable of your `rectangle`), the default constructor would have been called.

And the derived class constructor should call (or implicitly calls, if you forget it) the base class constructor:

```
   box () : rectangle () {}
```

BTW, compile your code with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) then use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step and query the various data.

Also, study the source code of some free software written in C++; it will teach you a lot.

Comment: Followed both the steps , still didn't work :(

Comment: There's no need for the derived class constructor to call a base class default constructor. That gets called implicitly.

Comment: exactly @juanchopanza !!

Comment: @Sachin "Still didn't work" That's because even though the code is proper now, your values are still 0.

Comment: @Sachin: you absolutely need to learn how to use the debugger. You won't be able to develop software in C++ without it.